# Is the DB work done in `execute` or in `fetch`?

Tags: python, mysql

I do not really understand, when a (MySQL) DB server will be "working" when I send a query to it:

Consider this Python3 code:

```
import mysql.connector as mc
connection = mc.connect (host = db_host, user = db_user, passwd = db_password, db = db_name)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM veryLongTable;")
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

The whole thing spends a few seconds in the `execute` line and a few minutes in the `fetchall` line.

What is happening there after all? Is the DB server executing the query and transmitting the "raw" result to me in `execute` and doing nothing at the `fetchall` (and the latter is just "read the result I got from the server"), or is it storing the result and only transmitting it when I call `fetchall`? Or is the query just "prepared" in `execute` and almost all work is done in `fetchall`?

Comment: `execute` executes the query on the server and returns an iterator. `fetchall` returns the rows.

Comment: Could you go a bit into detail please? *Who* returns the iterator and *who* returns the rows?

Comment: The server returns an iterator and stores it in the cursor with `execute`. Then the server returns multiple rows with `fetchall`. Both operations require a connection to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execute` executes the query on the server and returns an iterator. `fetchall` returns the rows.

The server returns an iterator and stores it in the cursor with `execute`. Then the server returns multiple rows with `fetchall`. Both operations require a connection to the server.

Almost all work is done in `execute`. The statement is executed and the data is prepared on the server to be fetched by the client. With `fetchall` the cursor iterates over the list of prepared rows and transfers them multiple of them at a time to the client.

*"or is it storing the result and only transmitting it when I call `fetchall`"* Yes, this is how it works.